# How to calculate radius in orb?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-descriptor

Studying ORB feature descriptors from it is the official paper I found it stating:

We empirically
choose `r` to be the patch size, so that that `x` and `y` run from
`[−r, r]`. As `|C|` approaches `0`,

I did not understand how `r` is calculated, please tell me how to calculate `r`.

I tried a lot to dig deeper using the internet but I couldn't find formula or explaining and I did not understand what it stated means.

Would you please explain it for me? And give me the formula if you may.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper says:

> "We empirically choose *r* to be the patch size,..."

In OpenCV a patch size of 31 (seems to be the standard value) is used.
The intensity patches with the specified size are used for the description of a FAST keypoint. Since ORB uses the BRIEF descriptor an image patch is transferred into a binary string which is later compared to match the keypoints. More details are found in the  [BRIEF paper](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/525/papers/calonder_eccv10.pdf).
So if you increase r you will increase the size of the binary string.
So the radius is not calculated by some formula but instead chosen by the developers/user.